# How to unset shipping rate?

Tags: shipping

How to unset shipping rate from _rates varible in Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result?

```
object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result)#663 (2) {
["_rates":protected]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method)#1585 (7) {
    ["_data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["carrier"]=>
      string(5) "fedex"
      ["carrier_title"]=>
      string(15) "Federal Express"
      ["method"]=>
      string(20) "GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY"
      ["method_title"]=>
      string(13) "Home Delivery"
      ["cost"]=>
      string(5) "27.33"
      ["price"]=>
      float(27.33)
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_origData":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method)#3391 (7) {
    ["_data":protected]=>
    array(6) {
      ["carrier"]=>
      string(8) "fred_3pl"
      ["carrier_title"]=>
      string(13) "Local Courier"
      ["method"]=>
      string(6) "b2c_a1"
      ["method_title"]=>
      string(24) "Free Delivery (Same Day)"
      ["cost"]=>
      float(0)
      ["price"]=>
      float(0)
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["_origData":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by unsetting it?

Comment: I want to remove one shipping rate.

Comment: Instead of dumping the variable try to elaborate a bit more with the what are you looking for in general, at whet part of the system etc. It can be that your approach is fundamentally false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't give any context in your question, here is how to unset a rate from the protected `$_rates` property of an `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result` instance.

The class interface only offers a method to retrieve all rates, or to add individual ones, you have to use reflection to modify the property value.

```
$ratesProperty = new \ReflectionProperty('Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result', '_rates');
$ratesProperty->setAccessible(true);
$rates = $ratesProperty->getValue($rateResultInstance);
unset($rates[0]); // Unset the rate you don't want
$ratesProperty->setValue($rateResultInstance, $rates);
```

It would be better to simply hinder Magento to add the method you don't want in the first place. But in order to point you in the right direction, you would have to give more information, as indicated by the comments to your question, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would work. I did it by extending Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result and adding a method that unsets.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you should be able to just unset the object you want to remove.

```
foreach($_rate as $r) {
   if($r->getMethod() == "fred_3pl")
      unset($r);
}
```

Comment: That would only work inside a class, I would like to do it outside. Thanks anyway.